# Asking for administrator privileges in MFC application only when it is needed

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, uac

I am developing an application in Visual C++ 2010, and the application is targeted to Windows 7. There is a task of writing some values to registry that will happen only in some special cases. And since in Windows 7, it is needed to have administrator privileges for doing so. How could I program my application in a way, that when it is needed for doing such actions, it asks for administrator privileges and it would not ask for administrator privileges at start time.
Thanks.

Comment: I don't think you can do this. Windows elevates the program at start time or not at all.

Comment: Doesn't CWinApp::WriteProfileString allow you to write to registry for your application?  I don't see the use-case for modifying outside of your application.   Just sayin'

Comment: CWinApp::WriteProfileString writes to HKCU. I think the requirement is to write to HKLM hive, which normal user accounts are not allowed to.

Comment: of course, the application wants to write sth to HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT. and I dont want my application to start with UAC prompt. I think there would be a way that just when it is needed it appears.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like Mark said, you cannot elevate your privilege on demand. A quick solution would be to write a separate executable that does the writing part and launch it using specific commandline parameters when you need. Of course this executable would have to have the 'requireAdministrator' privilege in its manifest.

You can also design this program as a service and setup an IPC mechanism, say using a named pipe. The pipe itself could be created with a security descriptor that allows normal user access to it ensuring that the program running at lower privilege will be able to write to it.

The purpose of the second approach is to eliminate the nasty UAC prompt that would appear with the first solution.

Comment: Thank you I think I have no choice, but writing different application with 'requireAdministrator' privilege in its manifest and included it my resource so when I need to do the stuff, I write that app to the temp folder and execute it. if I am not correct please notify me.

Comment: However, I think I have seen in some applications that when we push a special button for some stuff, the application just asks for administrative privileges.

Comment: Instead of writing a separate application, just do it in the same app - say if the app is started with /command:doit. You don't have to have an uac manifest since you can start any app with elevated privileges by using ShellExecuteEx() and "runas" as the verb.